# Error with Changing Variable Value with if Statement

Tags: javascript, html

I have radio buttons in an accordion, and depending on which radio buttons are selected, it will alert a different output. (There's a TON of extra CSS)

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        if(!this.classList.contains("active")) {
            closeAccordions();
        }
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}

function closeAccordions() {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].classList.remove("active");
        acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");

    }
}

var chanceoflive5 = 1;
var user;
function choose(choice){
    user = choice;
}

function changechanceoflive2(){
    if (user == 'bolts') {
        chanceoflive5 = 1;
    }
    else if (user == 'plates') {
        chanceoflive5 = 2;
    }

}

var chanceoflive6 = 1;
var user2;
function choose2(choice2){
    user = choice2;
}

function changechanceoflive3(){
    if (user2 == 'tie') {
        chanceoflive6 = 1;
    }
    else if (user2 == 'struts') {
        chanceoflive6 = 2;
    }

}

function nextpage(){
  var chanceoflive7 = chanceoflive5 + chanceoflive6;
  alert(chanceoflive7);
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #999;
}

form {
 margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
 margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-indent: 3.25em;
 margin-top: 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #9CE2AE;
 background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #999;
}

form {
 margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
 margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-indent: 3.25em;
 margin-top: 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #9CE2AE;
 background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}
```

```html
<hr>

<button class="accordion">Foundation Bolting</button>
<div class="panel">

    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1-1" class="radio" onclick="choose('bolts')" checked/>
      <label for="radio1-1">Foundation Bolts</label>
    </div>

     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1-2" class="radio" onclick="choose('plates')">
      <label for="radio1-2">Foundation Plates</label>
    </div>


</div>

<hr>

<button class="accordion">Wall Bracing</button>
<div class="panel">

  <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-1" class="radio" onclick="choose2('tie')" checked/>
      <label for="radio2-1">Strong Tie Retrofit Connectors</label>
    </div>

     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-2" class="radio" onclick="choose2('struts')">
      <label for="radio2-2">Angled Iron Struts</label>
    </div>

</div>

<hr>

<form action="">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button" onClick="changechanceoflive2(); changechanceoflive3(); nextpage()" align=center>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When you click the bottom option for each list, it should alert 4, but instead, it alerts 3. Why?

Comment: You probably mean `function choose2(choice2){user = choice2; }`. Otherwise `user2` will never have a value other than `undefined` leading to `chanceoflive6` having a max value of `1`. So `2+1=3`. Also you may want to have different names for variables or a more complex data structure, using (`someName0`, `someName1`, `etc`) will make things confusing very quickly.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek: Thanks for the advice on variables. Also, the solution was that instead of `user` (in your example), I had to put `user2`.

Comment: This is too much code. Can you provide an example showing the issue in a few dozen lines of stripped-down code?

Comment: @NathanChan Opps sorry I meant to say `user2 = choice2`, it was the point of my comment. Sorry about that.